# appengine endpoints tictactoe python on iOS example was written with java backend, how to make it work with python?

Tags: python, ios, google-app-engine, endpoints

The tictactoe example from google endpoints have versions for both java and python. These can be used with javascript, android, and iOS clients.

I want to use python endpoint with iOS client, but the source code for the iOS client found on github was written for java backend. What do I need to change for it to work with python endpoint.

Python endpoint: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python

iOS client:https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-ios

Update:
I guess I didnt phrase my question clearly, within the python endpoint file for tictactoe. the request is routed to static/js/render.js and static/js/base.js. I was wondering how to do those things with another python file, without going through those javascripts.

I want to know: what is the 'message'(the win or lose data, and what kind of data) is send by iOS to the endpoint. And how would the endpoint find this 'message' and use the api.method to put this 'message' to ndb?

Comment: Did you check out these docs? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients -- It basically tells you how to generate client libraries for both Android and iOS devices. I have no experience with Java Cloud Endpoints, but I'm sure the generation process is not that much different in Python...

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your backend ready, generating client libs for JS, Android or iOS is straightforward. Don't forget to run the same command in the terminal every time your API code changes (in order to update your client libs). 
[Here's](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients) a step by step guide on how to do it.